# Add meta data to the custom post type ARCHIVES page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

i can make an easy template for displaying custom post types.  but what i'd like to do is add some editable text to the top of my loop.

for example:

Hey wow, we really make cool products.  I think it'd be nice if this text wasn't had coded into the template.  any ideas?

product 1 
product 2 
product 3

and so on.

what is the easiest way to do that?  is it possible to attach meta to a post "type"? i know you can sort of do something like that for categories/tags/tax, etc.  but for a "type"?  should i make it a theme option?  would i be better served by making a post type and then displaying it through a taxonomy?

i do want the resulting permalink to be mysite.com/products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe wp_options is the best solution for this. It's easily editable in an theme option page, but still you must hand code a new option each time you register a new Custom Post Type.You can use these

- [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
- [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)
- [Creating Options Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Comment: forgot about this post.  i agree the options API is probably the best/only solution.