# Editable Meta Data for Custom Post Type Archive Template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

My question is one of theming best practices. I constantly running into an issue were I have to display editable content on a custom post type archive page for client work - such as an image, body of text or custom page title.  I've found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25756/add-meta-data-to-the-custom-post-type-archives-page) and it references the options api. I'm not looking for the easiest way, but rather the Wordpress way or maybe some insight from others.

Things I've tried in the past:

- create custom post type archive page, use the advanced custom field plugin to create a specific options page for custom post type archives. This works, but can be confusing to the user where they have to visit a theme options page for custom post type archive "meta" data, while all other page data is maintained through a page post.
- create a page template, write a function calling custom post type data with wp_query, then use the meta data for any other extra fields
- use the repeater field in advanced custom fields on page template, without using a custom post type. This could work if the data list was short and didn't need pagination, but will still be cumbersome accessing meta data from a separate post.

Essentially, I just want to start the conversation on how other developers solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After some offline conversations with other developers, I came to the solution of creating a settings page under any given custom post type menu. A quick way to get up and running is by using Advanced Custom Fields PRO with [this](http://www.jaredatchison.com/code/create-acf-options-page-custom-post-type-menu/) handy snippet by Jared Atchison:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create ACF setting page under Events CPT menu
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if ( function_exists( 'acf_add_options_sub_page' ) ){
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'title'      => 'Event Settings',
        'parent'     => 'edit.php?post_type=events',
        'capability' => 'manage_options'
    ));
}
```

Comment: FYI - Options are only supported by ACF PRO